# How to search based on a $OPTARG that I provided in a file?

Tags: linux, grep, options

I am trying to make an executable file for search a specific text. I want to retrieve any line in my data file that include the value that I pass it.
So I create a data file called `.addr_book` and I made an executable file called `lookup.ksh`

lookuo.ksh:

```
#!/bin/ksh

while getopts ":a:" option;
do
 case $option in
  a)
   echo searching for $OPTARG
   cat .addr_book | grep -o '$OPTARG.*' 
   ;;
  *)
   echo "invalid option -$OPTARG"
   ;;
 esac
done
```

when I execute the file like `./lookup.ksh -a test`
It will just show : `searching for test`

I think cat `.addr_book | grep -o '$OPTARG.*'`  have a problem.

Any help would be appreciate

Comment: Use double quotes around strings that contain variables that you'd like to expand, not single quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use single quotes around a variable expansion, you stop the shell from expanding that variable.  You should use double quotes instead.

Here is a suggestion for improvement:

```
#!/bin/sh

while getopts "a:" option; do
   case $option in
       a) word=$OPTARG ;;
       *) echo 'error' >&2
          exit 1
   esac
done

if [ -z "$word" ]; then
    echo 'Missing word to search for' >&2
    exit 1
fi

printf 'Searching for "%s"\n' "$word"
grep -o "$word.*" .addr_book
```

I've made a few changes:

- The script is not using `ksh`-specific features, so I made it a `/bin/sh` script.
- I separated the command line parsing from the main part of the script (the `grep`). This makes the script easier to maintain.
- The initial `:` in the `getopts` string tells `getopts` that you will handle invalid command line argument yourself. This is seldom needed as the diagnostic messages from `getopts` often are adequate.
- Diagnostic messages (anything that is not part of the normal output of the script, such as error messages or warnings) should go to the standard error stream (`>&2`).
- A diagnostic message is generated if the word to search for is missing or empty.
- Output of variable data should be done with `printf`.
- `cat` was removed.